# Apache-nifi not starting error

Tags: apache-nifi

[nifi.boosttrap.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shJGZ.png)
[nifi.app.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3wIz.png)

I have successful install nifi secure cluster but unable to start 
Error of nifi.app.log

ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-09-20 18:39:03,405 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2017-09-20 18:39:03,406 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).

Comment: There should be another error further up in the log.

Comment: @BryanBende i have attached screen shot of error

Comment: Is there anything in nifi-bootstrap.log at the same time?

Comment: I have added nifi.boosttrap.log @BryanBende

Answer (score 1):

it was not able to talk to "localhost:2181".I Checked “/etc/hosts”, found that there was not "127.0.0.1 ". so I Added  to "hosts"  as localhost  and restarted NiFi, it worked.